# using subprocess in python across os platforms

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, cross-platform

I am developing a software which includes a python script that runs bash commands using subprocess. Would I be able to run this particular script using windows in the future?

I basically am using three languages: Bash, C and Python.

I run all the scripts within python using bash commands.

`cat run.sh`

```
gcc [programName].c -o programName
./programName
```

or potentially just do:
`subprocess.call(["gcc",programName])`

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: What is bash doing that python can't?

Comment: so basically I have a bash script in the directory. It initially runs a executable using bash.  The rest of the bash commands are awk and sed which as Milosz said, I could run within python

Comment: @user171558 _It initially runs a executable using bash._ Can you be more specific? Doing the entire thing in Python might be your best bet.

Comment: @AMC There is something to this I can't explain properly. I'd appreciate it if you read this. So I installed this genomic variant detector off of github and compiled it using `make`. I run it using bash: `gatk HaplotypeCaller --file sequence.fastq --dbsnp dbsnp.vcf > output.txt` which gives me a tab separated output. I started by processing this using awk. I then performed some mathematical analyses in python. I thought of running all the bash commands from within python including `gatk ...` However, I realized this is not doable on windows.

Comment: @user171558 I read your comment, but I don't see an actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on this a bit recently. If you want to have code that works both on Unix and Windows, I'd advise you to use e.g. `os.remove` or `os.rename` wherever possible instead of `rm` or `mv`, `glob.glob` instead of `ls`, and only use `subprocess` to run external commands (remember they'll have `.exe` extensions most of the time -- you might check `os.name` to decide whether to include it or not). You might also want to rewrite all your `grep`s, `awk`s or `sed`s as Python functions.

The point is, even though technically you can install Bash on Windows and run your Python code from the console, it seemed to me the code from `subprocess` was always run in CMD or PowerShell anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I assume I have to avoid coding in bash for this particular case if I want to ever run the python file on windows.

Comment: Yup, I started out super-hyped with this recent 'bash on Windows' promise but it turned out not to be very robust. Fortunately, `os`, `shutil` and `sys` have lots of bash-like tools for file manipulation, and many others can be easily emulated with built-in methods such as `str.replace()`.